# Peut-être + deux verbes successifs

Tags: grammaire, verbes

Prenons la phrase suivante :

> Je mange et je suis fatigué.

On peut bel et bien omettre le deuxième "je" :

> Je mange et suis fatigué.

Ajoutons un "peut-être que" :

> Peut-être que je mange et que je suis fatigué.

À mon sens, on ne peut pas faire sans le deuxième "que".

Maintenant, dans un registre plus élevé :

> Peut-être mange-je et suis-je fatigué.

Est-ce que cette phrase est correcte ? Et puis-je supprimer le deuxième "je" ainsi :

> Peut-être mange-je et suis fatigué.

Je pense que non, mais je n'en suis pas sûr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lorsqu'il n'y a pas de lien logique entre deux verbes partageant le même sujet, normalement le pronom est repris :

> Je mange et je suis fatigué. ✔
> Je mange et suis fatigué. ***?*** (pas de lien implicite)

> Je mange et je suis rassasié. ✔
> Je mange et suis rassasié.  ✔ (lien implicite)

Avec *peut-être que*, on omet souvent le deuxième *peut-être* mais le *que* est répété, sinon la phrase est ambiguë :

> Peut-être que je mange et peut-être que je suis rassasié.   ✔ (lourd)
> Peut-être que je mange et que je suis rassasié.  ✔
> Peut-être que je mange et je suis rassasié.  ✘

L'inversion avec le pronom *je* entraîne une modification de la terminaison des verbes en /-ʒə/ :

> Peut-être mange-je et suis-je rassasié.  ✘
> Peut-être **mangé**-je et suis-je rassasié. ✔ (correct, mais rarissime)

On ne peut pas supprimer de pronom dans cette inversion :

> Peut-être mangé-je et suis rassasié. ✘